# Registering implicit/explicit typecast operators in dwscript

Tags: delphi, operator-overloading, dwscript

Is it possible to register an implicit and/or explicit typecasting operator from Delphi?

I found http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/issues/detail?id=124, but it seems to deal with in-script operator overloading and it's a fairly old issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible, the currently supported implicit conversions are still hard-coded in the compiler. There is an incremental WIP initiated to refactor that (https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/issues/detail?id=246), but it still hasn't been completed.